# jquery .animate not working in my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery is not working in a simple project I am making for some of my students. I have a previous project I just ran which works just fine. The problem is that when i click on the div (there is only one) nothing happens and it should slide. Any help would be apricated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#frog").click(function() {
                $( "#frog" ).animate({height: "20px"}, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #frog{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
            left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>I hate JS!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <h2>Programming Languages</h2>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>Javascript</li>
        <li>C++</li>
        <li>C#</li>
        <li>ruby</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <h2>Top 3 Best Animations</h2>
        <h4><li>Slide</li></h4>
    </ol>
    <div id="frog"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `script` tag has both a `src` *and* content:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#frog").click(function() {
            $( "#frog" ).animate({height: "20px"}, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Per HTML [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), it can have one *or* the other, but not both.  Separate it into two elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#frog").click(function() {
            $( "#frog" ).animate({height: "20px"}, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```